# Does blackberry sdk have support for reading data via the 3.5mm audio jack?

Tags: java, blackberry

I'm trying to build an app for blackberry and I need to be able to read data from an hardware I'l plug into the audio jack. Is it possible on blackberry? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I don't think so. While somehow possible, this is not what an audio jack is made for. It is an analog interface. While some also have an input channel (e.g. for microphone) it is made for capturing an analog audio signal, which goes through an analog digital converter. This gives you finally a digital audio signal.

You could misuse it for your needs. For that your external hardware has to encode the data as an audio stream and send it by itself. Your app has to decode the audio stream back to data. I guess there is SDK functionallity to get the audio stream, but the rest you have to do yourself.

While all this might be technically possible, I can't emphasize enough what a really really really bad idea this is. Not to mention the effort.